# style element with 'scoped' attribute deemed invalid by W3C

Tags: html, stylesheet, w3c-validation

I have a `style` element within the `body` of a HTML document like this:

```
<body>
<style scoped >
…
```

But when validating with W3C I get this error:

> Element `style` not allowed as child of element `body` in this context.
>   (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)

I thought that if you added the `scoped` attribute you could add the `style` element in the `body`. I need to add it in the `body` because we don't have access to the `head`.

Is there something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The `scoped` attribute was removed before HTML5 became a W3C Recommendation, so you cannot use it in HTML5 documents.

Therefore, you can use the [`style` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/document-metadata.html#the-style-element) only where "[metadata content](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/dom.html#metadata-content-0) is expected" (i.e., in the `head` element).

The [`scoped` attribute](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/document-metadata.html#attr-style-scoped) is still part of the Editor's Draft of HTML 5.1 Nightly ([stable link to current Working Draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-html51-20140617/document-metadata.html#attr-style-scoped)).

Comment: On top of that, the scoped attribute is still poorly implemented (though for the purposes of this question it doesn't really matter). It's probably why it was removed from HTML 5.0.